# Does this java parameter would insert a row into sql server?

Tags: java, sql-server

I have Java code that I want to test on SQL server if it would insert a row. Currently, I don't have a tool to test this code yet. Here is the code:

```
MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
parameters.addValue("id", "1"); // primary key
parameters.addValue("date", new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York").getInstance().getTimeInMillis()); // Calendar object for date
return parameters;
```

and SQL Server table would be something like id with INTEGER and date with DATETIME2 (this must be DATETIME2).

I would like to know if this would insert a row.

Problem I'm having: I have this code which currently works with Oracle database. I am using HSQLDB to test it on my unit test by creating duplicate table with same column and data type. Now, I need to migrate database from Oracle to SQL Server. As a process, I am making the project compatible for both Oracle and SQL Server without writing separate code.

In my new unit test, I use HSQLDB to create table and columns. For some reason, HSQLDB throws `org.hsqldb.HsqlException: data exception: invalid datetime format` error when this `Calendar` type is passed in as parameter. I want to make sure if this problem is from HSQLDB or SQL Server.

Comment: Hi! Have you tried changing the date format? Also, why can't you just host/run a local sql server that you can configure and test with?

Comment: I can't change the date format because it was decided by people above me. Currently, I don't have local sql server and dev sql server is on vpn which is having an issue..

Comment: `Calendar` is a type that is not defined for use in the JDBC specification (except in limited use to pass time zone information when using `set/getTime` and `set/getTimestamp`). Support for `Calendar` and its sub-classes is therefor non-standard and driver specific.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel sorry, I updated to Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(). Forgot to add last part.

Comment: Sounds like Mark has a good idea about it. I'd suggest joda datetime instead. If I understand correctly that Calendar is its own library

Comment: Most drivers will not accept a long value for what is a date/time type. Either use a `java.time.LocalDateTime` or a `java.sql.Timestamp`.

Comment: I just double-checked, and the JDBC specification actually does specify support for `java.util.Calendar`, but I'm not sure if all drivers actually implement that support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code tries to assign a `Long` value to a (JDBC) `TIMESTAMP` column. Setting a `long` (or `Long`) value on a `TIMESTAMP` column is not defined in JDBC. If this works in Oracle, then that is a non-standard extension specific to the Oracle driver, and therefor is not guaranteed to work in other drivers.

You will need to use the types that are defined by JDBC. For a `TIMESTAMP` (without time zone) column, the [JDBC 4.3 specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr221/index3.html) only defines support for the following Java types:

- `java.sql.Timestamp` (primary type, but recommendation is to use `java.time.LocalDateTime` instead)
- `java.lang.String`
- `java.sql.Date` (recommendation is to use `java.time.LocalDate` instead)
- `java.sql.Time` (recommendation is to use `java.time.LocalTime` instead)
- `java.util.Calendar` (though I'm not sure if this is commonly supported)
- `java.util.Date` (though I'm not sure if this is commonly supported)
- `java.time.LocalDate` (introduced in JDBC 4.2)
- `java.time.LocalTime` (introduced in JDBC 4.2)
- `java.time.LocalDateTime` (introduced in JDBC 4.2)

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem with the JDBC driver, but I wouldn't blame it overly much; Calendar is horrible API, and obsolete to boot. Don't use it.

The 'safest' date/time type to send is an instance of `java.sql.Timestamp`. The 'best' date/time type to send is something from the `java.time` package, preferably a `ZonedDateTime`. If your JDBC driver lets you do that, do that. If it does not, grumble, grit your teeth, fire off a bug report with the JDBC driver maker, and use `java.sql.Timestamp`.

Comment: I forgot to add last part `Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()`. sorry :(

Comment: I think his answer is still saying that you shouldn't use Calendar.

Comment: Support for `java.time.ZonedDateTime` is not defined by the JDBC specification. JDBC only specifies `java.time.LocalTime`/`java.time.LocalTimestamp`/`java.sql.Time`/`java.sql.Timestamp`/`java.sql.Date` and string for `TIME/TIMESTAMP [WITHOUT TIME ZONE]`/`DATE`, and only `java.time.OffsetTime`/`java.time.OffsetDateTime` and string for `TIME/TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, any other types used for these types are **non-standard** and support for other types will be different or absent across JDBC drivers.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Interesting! And that is quite unfortunate. Do you know why the JDBC spec team decided not to add, e.g. .getOffsetDateTime() to ResultSet and co whilst still encoding that these types are supposed to be supported?

Comment: The `get/set/updateXxx` are considered a historic design [error] derived from the desire to support primitive types (instead of wrapper types). It was then decided to extend this design to the reference types as well. However, I think in JDBC 4.1, when support for `java.math.BigInteger` was added, they decided to stop adding `get/set/updateXxx` methods, and instead decided that using `get/set/updateObject` was the way forward. JDBC 4.1 also introduced `getObject​(int columnIndex, Class<T> type)`. This was then used also in JDBC 4.2 when defining `java.time` support (and `WITH TIME ZONE` types)